# Tikz matrix vertical alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble with the vertical alignment of the nodes in a tikz matrix. I have two plots next to each other. I want them to be aligned with respect to the center of their bounding boxes, but they end up aligned with respect to the zero coordinate (the abscissa in this case). Based on other questions (e.g., [Aligning matrix nodes in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75136/aligning-matrix-nodes-in-tikz)), I've tried with various combinations of `align=base`, `align=center`, `anchor=center`, etc, without success.

Below is the code and corresponding output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm, cells={xscale=0.7, yscale=2},
align=center, nodes={rectangle, anchor=center, align=center}]
{
  \draw [->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0);
  \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.3);
  \draw [blue, ultra thick, domain=-4:4, samples=100] plot
  (\x, {1/sqrt(1 + \x*\x)});
  &
  \draw [->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0);
  \draw [->] (0,-0.6) -- (0,0.6);
  \draw [blue, ultra thick, domain=-4:4, samples=100] plot
  (\x, {-0.4*pi*atan(\x)/180});
  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{How to align?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any idea about how to vertically align the center of the cell's bounding boxes?

Comment: A quick fix is to change both y-axis to (0,-0.6) -- (0,1.2);

Comment: @Jesse Thanks. I would also need to offset the plot. And then I would need to change the offset every time I change the plot.

Comment: If a non-tikz solution may be proposed, I'd split the figures and deal with the subcaption package which allows you to align figures in the center, top or bottom. This is particulary easy as all your plots have the same dimensions (height x width)

Comment: The problem is that y=0 is the same in both plots because they are part of the same picture.  So one approach would be to separate them into two separate tikzpictures and simply put them inside a `\makebox` separated by a `\qquad` space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `matrix`, just declare each graphic as a separate `tikzpicture` which will be treated as any other `box` in `LaTeX`. No need for `\makebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.7,yscale=2]
  \draw [->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0);
  \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.3);   
  \draw [blue, ultra thick, domain=-4:4, samples=100] plot
  (\x, {1/sqrt(1 + \x*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.7,yscale=2]
  \draw [->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0);
  \draw [->] (0,-0.6) -- (0,0.6);
  \draw [blue, ultra thick, domain=-4:4, samples=100] plot
  (\x, {-0.4*pi*atan(\x)/180});
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{How to align?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just replaced the `hfill` by `hspace{2em}` to avoid a large empty space in between the plots.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the alignment by using the tikzlibrary `matrix`, adding `matrix of nodes` to your matrix options, and drawing your plots as nested tikzpictures.

Here the full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix [matrix of nodes,column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm, align=center,
        nodes={rectangle, anchor=center, align=center}]
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.7, yscale=2]
        \draw [->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0);
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.3);
        \draw [blue, ultra thick, domain=-4:4, samples=100] plot
        (\x, {1/sqrt(1 + \x*\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.7, yscale=2]
        \draw [->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0);
        \draw [->] (0,-0.6) -- (0,0.6);
        \draw [blue, ultra thick, domain=-4:4, samples=100] plot
        (\x, {-0.4*pi*atan(\x)/180});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{How to align?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the result

[image]

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture`s has its own casualties :-)

Comment: Yes, I agree, but here it just works fine (as far as I see). In addition you do not have to adjust the pictures manually and to compute the `yshift` by yourself, although this is easy in this example.

Comment: @HarishKumar: besides compilation time, what are the major casualities of nesting TikZ pictures?

Answer (score 3):

You can put the first graph inside a `scope` and lower it by `-.65cm` (i.e., to the mid point of y-axis).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm, cells={xscale=0.7, yscale=2},
align=center, nodes={rectangle, anchor=center, align=center}]
{
   \begin{scope}[yshift=-0.65cm]
  \draw [->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0);
  \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.3);   
  \draw [blue, ultra thick, domain=-4:4, samples=100] plot
  (\x, {1/sqrt(1 + \x*\x)});
  \end{scope}
  &
  \draw [->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0);
  \draw [->] (0,-0.6) -- (0,0.6);
  \draw [blue, ultra thick, domain=-4:4, samples=100] plot
  (\x, {-0.4*pi*atan(\x)/180});
  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{How to align?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]